# Adding link on title its in description but not in title see screenshots attached

Tags: plugins, php, widgets, html

This should be simple fix. I am learning php so am not that good to spot the obvious. Here's the website http://goo.gl/tE4OSO. here's what I want [http://imgur.com/qZXPPYu](https://imgur.com/qZXPPYu) .

Here the code I believe is responsible for the linking

```
$custom_class = '';



                if ( $display_link && ! $cancelled ) {



                    $custom_class = 'wolf-show-linked';



                } elseif ( $cancelled ) {



                    $custom_class = 'wolf-show-cancelled';

                }

                ?>

                <tr class="wolf-single-date <?php echo sanitize_html_class( $custom_class );  ?>">

                    <td class="wolf-show-date"><?php echo  wp_kses_post( $date ); ?></td>



                    <?php if ( $artist ) : ?>

                    <td>

                        <?php if ( $display_link ) : ?>

                        <a title="<?php _e( 'View details', 'wolf' ); ?>" class="wolf-show-entry-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post_id ); ?>">
                        <?php endif; ?>






                            <?php echo '<strong>'.sanitize_text_field( $artist ).'</strong>'; ?>




        <?php if ( $display_link ) : ?>

                        </a>

                        <?php endif; ?>
```

Again I want to remove the link from subtitle and have the title linked. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that is the right code. Do a multi file search of the whole theme. And make sure the code is for a widget.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way around this , I moved the title inside the   and that made it as a link as well , since I wanted it to have the same link anyways.

```
                    <a title="<?php _e( 'View details', 'wolf' ); ?>" class="wolf-show-entry-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post_id ); ?>">
```

Hope this could help some other some other day as well.

```
                    <?php endif; ?>






                        <?php echo '<strong>'.sanitize_text_field( $artist ).'</strong>'; ?>




    <?php if ( $display_link ) : ?>

                    </a>

                    <?php endif; ?>
```